# How to query all article types

Tags: knowledge

I have a question. In our SF org, we have 2 article types. Knowledge, attachment. How to query all article types. Like below image, I have to query and show the article type.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you like to query all ArticleType use this SOQL.

For more information, refer [KnowledgeArticleVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleversion.htm)

```
SELECT Title, ArticleType
FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion 
WHERE PublishStatus='Online'
AND language ='en_US'
```

**Update based on comments**

Article Type is an object which is getting stored like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
                <fullName>articlefilemetadata</fullName>
                <apiAccessLevel>Unrestricted</apiAccessLevel>

                <types>
                <members>newarticle__kav.description__c</members>
                <name>CustomField</name>
                </types>
                <types>
                <members>newarticle__kav</members>
                <name>CustomObject</name>
                </types>

                </Package>
```

So, you need to query metadata. Refer https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi for using the query.

Comment: I have used this query, but it shows all the articles. I need to show the article types on the picklist. Like above image.

Comment: updated my answer